# can't get input index what I want

Tags: jquery

my code like this:

```
<input type="text" id="getIndex"/>
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" name="abcGid1" />
<input type="text" name="abcGid2" />
<input type="text" name="abcGid3" />
<input type="text" name="abcGid4" />

var getData=[
    {"index":0,"value":"1111"},
    {"index":1,"value":"2222"},
    {"index":2,"value":"3333"},
    {"index":3,"value":"4444"},
];
$.each(getData,function(i,n){
    $("input[name*='Gid']").eq(n.index).val(n.value);
});
 $("input[name*='Gid']").blur(function(){
    $('#getIndex').val($(this).index());
 });
```

why `$(this).index()` return 2 3 4 5,
but `n.index` is `0 1 2 3`  can work.
I want `$(this).index()` return `0 1 2 3`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WinKiFlyMe/ZaCXd/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The no-arg version of .index() returns the index based on the sibling elements, try another version of index() as given below it gives the index of the elements passed as the argument in the matched set of elements

```
$("input[name*='Gid']").blur(function () {
    $('#getIndex').val($("input[name*='Gid']").index(this));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5V93D/)

or

```
$("input[name*='Gid']").blur(function () {
    $('#getIndex').val($(this).index("input[name*='Gid']"));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/H8hb2/)

But I would recommend you cache the selector as

```
var $grds = $("input[name*='Gid']");
$.each(getData, function (i, n) {
    $grds.eq(n.index).val(n.value);
});
$("input[name*='Gid']").blur(function () {
    $('#getIndex').val($grds.index(this));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2BR7j/)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your logic. $(this).index() is an index of element in form, not in your selector $("input[name*='Gid']") result.

Try this:

```
$("input[name*='Gid']").each(function(i,n){
    $(this).blur(function(){
    $('#getIndex').val(i);
    });
});
```